# Bug with Archive utility and Column view

Tags: finder, archive

On OSX Mojave, version 10.14.2. Related to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317442/85983), which does not solve the issue reported here.

**Step 1.** Configure `Archive Utility` to prevent opening new Finder windows:

- Close all Finder windows.
- In Spotlight, select `Archive Utility.app`. This does not open any window, but you should be able to access `Archive Utility / Preferences...` in the menu bar.
- Open `Preferences...`, and untick the option `Reveal archive in Finder` at the bottom.
- Open a Terminal, and type: `killall Finder`.

**Step 2.** Create an archive of a nested folder:

- In Finder, with column view for example with folders `A/B/C`, select folder `B`. You should see the contents of that folder, including folder `C`.
- **Without left-clicking folder `C`** (as in, you should not see its contents in the next column), right-click on folder `C` and select `Compress "C"`.
- An archive `C.zip` is created in folder `B`, without opening a new Finder window.

**Step 3.** Problematic behaviour:

- Now select folder `C`, such that its contents appear in the next column.
- Then right-click `C`, and select `Compress "C"` again.
- A new archive `C 2.zip` is created in folder `B`, **and a new Finder window is opened.**

This is contrary to the preferences set in the Archive Utility (step 1), and inconsistent with the behaviour obtained in step 2; in other words, this is a bug. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Please can you report this directly to Apple via their [feedback pages](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) or through [Bug Reporter](https://bugreporter.apple.com).

Comment: Why call `killall Finder`? This seems extreme and may cause unintended side effects.

Comment: @GrahamMiln I will report this at some point this week. You are right that `killall Finder` may have unintended side-effects; I included this command to leave no ambiguity that the archiver settings were taken into account in steps 2 & 3.